# Trouble finding the inverse of $f(x) = x + \frac{1}{x}$ .

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Let $ f: \Bbb R - \{0\} \rightarrow \Bbb R \;\text{ given by } f(x) = x + \frac{1}{x} . \text{Find} $

> $f(f^{-1}(\Bbb R))$ , $\Bbb R = \text{real numbers}$.

For this problem I know one needs to find the inverse in order to solve.

$ y = x+ \frac{1}{x} \Rightarrow y^2 = \left( x+\frac{1}{x} \right)^{2}$

$y^2 = x^2+2 + \frac{1}{x^2}  $

one should arrive at the conclusion. $$f(x)^{-1} = \frac{x \pm \sqrt{x^2-4} }{2}$$

Yet I am having trouble at arriving at that conclusion. Could anyone show me how to do it arithmetically.

Comment: We don't need the inverse to solve the original problem.

Comment: Actually, there is no inverse function $f^{-1}$ here because $f$ is not onto. For example, there is no $x$ such that $f(x)=1$.

Comment: $f^{-1}(\mathbb R)$ is not the image of the inverse of $f$ but is the preimage  of $\mathbb R$ w.r.t. $f$.

Comment: Ah, okay. The notation is ambiguous. In any case, he can not find the inverse of $f$ as stated in the title.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We do not need to find a formula for the "inverse function" to answer the original question. Indeed since $f(x)$ is not one to one, the inverse function does not exist.

By symmetry, we can begin by confining attention to positive $x$. Note that $$\left(x+\frac{1}{x}\right)^2=\left(x-\frac{1}{x}\right)^2+4.$$
So (for positive $x$) our function is very large near $0$, then decreases steadily until $x=1$, where it reaches a minimum of $2$, then increases steadily, taking on arbitrarily large values.

It follows that as $x$ ranges over the positive reals, $f(x)$ ranges over all reals $\ge 2$.

Similarly, as $x$ ranges over the negative reals, $f(x)$ ranges over all reals $\le -2$.

It follows that $f(f^{-1}(\mathbb{R}))=(-\infty,-2]\cup [2,\infty)$.

Comment: I guess it is worth also pointing out explicitly that since the codomain of $f$ is $\mathbb{R}$, the preimage $f^{-1}(\mathbb{R})$ is just the domain of $f$. Therefore $f(f^{-1}(\mathbb{R}))$ is just the range (image of the domain) of $f$.

Comment: One your second line, $\left( x+\frac{1}{x} \right)^2$ = $(x-\frac{1}{x})^2+4.$ I am having trouble understanding why they are equal. What is meant by symmetry exactly? Where does the +4 come from?

Comment: Expand both sides. You will find the left side is equal to the right side. Actually, you have done all the basic work already. Essentially the same calculation as yours shows that $\left(x-\frac{1}{x}\right)^2=x^2-2+\frac{1}{x^2}$. The $4$ is from $2=(-2)+4$. The symmetry is that $f(-x)=-f(x)$, so if we know everything about $f$ for positive $x$, then we know everything about $f$ for negative $x$ by just changing signs.

Answer (score 4):

You might not need to compute an inverse in order to solve this, but it may help to think about it. I would say

$$\begin{align*}
f(x) &= x + \frac{1}{x}\\
&= \frac{x^2}{x} + \frac{1}{x}\\
&= \frac{x^2 + 1}{x}\\
\\
y &\equiv \frac{x^2 + 1}{x}\\
xy &= x^2 + 1\\
0 &= x^2 - xy + 1\\
\end{align*}$$

Then solve for $x$ as a function of $y$ using, for example, the quadratic formula.

Answer (score 2):

Write it as $x^2-xy+1=0$ and use quadratic formula for $x$ you have relation for x in terms of $y$

Answer (score 1):

Don't need inverse and looking for inverse will lead you astray.

As for every $x \ne 0; f(x)$ exists and $f(x) = c \in f(\mathbb R) \subset \mathbb R$ for some $c \in f(\mathbb R)$. So $x \in f^{-1}(\mathbb R)$.  If $x = 0$, $f(x)$ is undefined so $x \not \in f^{-1}(\mathbb R)$.

So $f^{-1}(\mathbb R) = \mathbb R - \{0\}$.

Basically for any $f$, $f^{-1}(X)$ is an, albeit confusing, way to state the preimage part of the domain that gets mapped to X.  As $X = \mathbb R$, the pre-image is the entire domain.

So all this question is asking is to find:

$f(\mathbb R -\{0\})$.  In other words to find the codomain/image of the function.  A bit of fussing and you can figure it is $(-\infty, 2] \cup [2, \infty)$.

====

Bit of fussing: For $x > 0$. If $x = 1$, $x + \frac 1x = 2$.  If $x \ne 1$ then either $x > 1; \frac 1x < 1$ or $x< 1; \frac 1x > 1$.  Wolog assume $x = 1 + \delta > 1$ then $1 - \delta^2 < 1 \implies (1 - \delta)(1 + \delta) < 1 \implies 1- \delta < \frac 1{1+\delta} \implies x + \frac 1x = 1 + \delta + \frac 1{1+\delta} > 1 + \delta + 1 - \delta = 2$.

So $f(\mathbb R^+) \subset [2,\infty)$.

As $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb R^+$ and for all $y > 2; f(y) > y$ it follows $\exists c;2 < c < y; f(c) = y$ and $f(\mathbb R^+) = [2,\infty)$.

As $f(-x) = -x - 1/x = -(x+1/x) = -f(x)$, $f(\mathbb R - \{0\}) = (-\infty, 2] \cup[2,\infty)$